# visible binding with selectpicker not working

Tags: knockout.js, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/c2gbak5m/) example and selectpicker is working but visible binding is not working. If I add visible: false to this example I can still see the selectpicker. Does anybody know how to hide the selectpicker using visible binding?

```
<select data-bind="options: item().options, value: item().value,visible: false, selectPicker: {}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bootstrap picker hides the actual `<select>` element and injects new UI elements to replace it. The "advanced" solution would be to extend the binding in such a way that forwards the `visible` binding to one of the generated-by-bootstrap elements.

*However*, I think you should go with the simple solution: wrapping the `<select>` in an extra element to support the `visible` binding:

```
<div data-bind="visible: false" style="display: inline-block;">
  <select ...></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is the easiest way.